# What happen when hard shutdown?

Tags: shutdown, freeze

Yesterday a videogame freezes two times and the only way I found is to shutdown the PC by long press shutdown button.
Now I'm wondering what happens when I do that, it can cause damage to some software?
If the videogame freezes again, there is other way to close it without hard shutdown?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [What should I do when Ubuntu freezes?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/4408/what-should-i-do-when-ubuntu-freezes)

Comment: That's very helpful and I'll follow that advice in the future if happen again. But, since I power-off my system in the "hard" way, I'm interested to know if I ruined some piece of software and how to check it, so the link above don't answer this question